# Android 5 WebView .How to get at MediaPlayer using reflection

Tags: android, webview

In my code I use

```
Class<?> c1  = Class.forName("android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen$VideoSurfaceView");

Field f1 = c1.getDeclaredField("this$0");
f1.setAccessible(true);

Class <?> c2 = f1.getType().getSuperclass();

Object obj_html5VideoViewInstance = f1.get(focusedChild);

Field f3 = c2.getDeclaredField("mUri");
```

to get at MediaPlayer and at the Uri this media player is playing .

But in android 5 the class `android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen` do not exists .

How can I apply the reflection in adroid 5 to get at the mUri ?

Anyone any ideas about this?

Comment: I think this is a security hole that was fixed in JellyBean - https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=129859614

Comment: I just read that article , but here addJavascriptInterface() is not used . I just need to get at the class (for old android HTML5VideoFullScreen$VideoSurfaceView ) that has the mPlayer (MediaPlayer instance)  and mUri variable  .The class no more exists cause something changed but there must be a way to go at MediaPlayer in android 5 too

Comment: If you are trying to access native player you'll need to create a JavascriptInterface to access it. If you are only concerned with the HTML5 Video player, can't you just reference the DOM to get the value?

Comment: What i most want to get is the Url the media player is playing from my webview .Using the code i posted I can get the 'mUrl 'that is stored in that class (missing from android 5) and passed to MediaPlayer class to play it. I do not know what 'reference the DOM' means ,can you give more tips?

Comment: Ugh - I just realized you've got code in Java - my bad. As your app is hosting the webview, you should be able to parse the input for the html <video> tag to find out what the url is. If more than one, then you will need to inject in JavaScript code to read out the attributes, which you could access via addJavascriptInterface

Comment: @MorrisonChang, javascript will not work if 'video' tags are not located directly in HTML page, e.g. in iframes. It is a common case. That's why I'm also interested in reflection usage.